# What is the limit of request for a free user in the Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

The foursquare place API states that it gives $200 for every month and if the API call cost more than $200 we need to pay for the further usage of the API. How many request can be sent per month for $200?

I am currently using the API for a day an the $200 has been reduced to $199.46. I need to know the exact request /per month.

Comment: The price is charged per 1000 requests. You can see detailed estimations on the pricing page: https://location.foursquare.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

You are not limited to a number of requests per month, rather there is a charge per 1000 requests.

The pricing varies slightly between the Core Attributes and the Rich Attributes, so the cost depends on the data you retrieve.  The pricing table, including sliders for estimating costs are available at:

https://location.foursquare.com/pricing/

The "base cost" in this table is the "cost per 1000 requests".  For example, if you are only using the Places Search endpoint and fetching the Core attributes, you can make 40k requests/month using the $200 credit.  If fetching the Rich Attributes, you can make just over 30k requests/month using the $200 credit.

[image: Places API Search Endpoint Cost Estimator]

For pay-as-you-go, there is a Rate Limit (throttle) of 50 requests/second.
(Login to your Foursquare Developer Account to view: https://location.foursquare.com/developer/reference/rate-limits)

> Usage of the Places API is subject to rate limits. The applicable queries per second (QPS) rate limit, calculated across all endpoints in total, is as follows:

> Enterprise Customers: 100 QPS; or
> Pay as You Go & Sandbox Customers: 50 QPS.